# regarding parallel structure

Tags: parallelism

Pluripotent genes are activated in injured tissue cells and **play** important role in regeneration.

In the above sentence, should "play" be changed to "played" for parallel construction. Pls help.

Comment: Why do you think "play" should be in the past tense? Do you want to imply that these genes *no longer play* an important role in regeneration? Vasu, you might also find our sibling site [ell.se] is a useful source of information. Please note that [elu.se] is a question and answer site for *linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts*.

Answer (score 1):

No, because they continue to play an important role after being *activated*. This sentence describes a sequence of actions which happen one after another, rather than two things happening in parallel.

Also, it should be play **an** important role.